# iPhone - sorting an array of dictionaries by CGRect's origin.x

Tags: iphone, ios, sorting, nsarray

I have an array of dictionaries. 
Each dictionary is like this

```
object, @"myObject",
[NSValue valueWithCGRect:myRect], @"rect",
nil
```

How do I sort that array by myRect.origin.x ?

I know that objective-c has smart ways to sort arrays of dictionaries. My problem here is that I want to sort by the x coordinate of myRect and myRect is wrapped in a NSValue... any way to do that with a magic command? I know you guys are magicians! :D

thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The cleanest way is probably to use a method like `sortUsingComparator:` or `sortedArrayUsingComparator` (depending on the mutability of the array) and define a custom comparator (a block taking two parameters and returning an `NSComparisonResult`) that unpacks your rects and compare their x-coordinates.

**edit**: Well, since everyone else is providing code, here's mine:

```
[array sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    CGRect rect1 = [[obj1 valueForKey:@"rect"] CGRectValue];
    CGRect rect2 = [[obj2 valueForKey:@"rect"] CGRectValue];

    if(rect1.origin.x < rect2.origin.x) {
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    } else if(rect1.origin.x > rect2.origin.x) {
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    } else {
        return NSOrderedSame;
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 3):

There's no magic, but it's not free, either. :) You're looking for `-[NSArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:]`. If your array is an `NSMutableArray` then you can use `-[NSMutableArray sortUsingComparator:]`.

A comparator is a block which returns an `NSComparisonResult` and takes two objects. Here's the definition in `NSObjCRuntime.h`:

```
typedef NSComparisonResult (^NSComparator)(id obj1, id obj2);
```

The block should take the objects, cast them to dictionaries, extract the NSValues from each back into rects and return the result of comparing the X coordinate fields.

Psuedocode, assuming an `NSMutableArray`:

```
[myArray sortUsingComparator:^(id obj1, id obj2) {
    NSDictionary *dict1 = (NSDictionary *)obj1;
    NSDictionary *dict2 = (NSDictionary *)obj2;
    // Extract each of the NSValues
    // Compare the x values
    if (xValue1 == xValue2) return NSOrderedSame;
    return (xValue1 < xValue2) ? NSOrderedAscending : NSOrderedDescending;
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it (it's not quite a one-liner I'm afraid):

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [unsortedArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id obj1, id obj2) {
    ([[obj1 objectForKey:@"rect"] CGRectValue].x < [[obj2 objectForKey:@"rect"] CGRectValue].x)? NSOrderedAscending : NSOrderedDescending;
}];
```